# Insert multidimensional array json in mysql with laravel

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

Im trying to insert this multidemensional array from a nested json but im not sure how to tackle this. The array shows as the following when printed:

```
{ 
    "CompanyCode": "12345", 
    "CustomerNumber": "ABC0012300DEF", 
    "RequestID": "2017262221400000001975", 
    "ChannelType": "2014", 
    "CustomerName": "Customer Virtual Account", 
    "CurrencyCode": "IDR", 
    "PaidAmount": "60000.00", 
    "TotalAmount": "100000.00", 
    "SubCompany": "", 
    "TransactionDate": "15/03/2014 22:07:40", 
    "Reference": "", 
    "DetailBills": [ 
        { 
            "BillAmount": "25000.00", 
            "BillNumber": "1234567890", 
            "BillSubCompany": "00002", 
            "BillReference": "12345678900" 
        }, 
        { 
            "BillAmount": "35000.00", 
            "BillNumber": "2234567891", 
            "BillSubCompany": "00003", 
            "BillReference": "22345678901" 
        } 
    ], 
    "FlagAdvice": "N", 
    "Additionaldata": "" 
}
```

here's my code in laravel with db::insert :

```
DB::insert('insert into bca_company_payload (companyCode, customerNumber, requestID, channelType, customerName, paidAmount, totalAmount, subCompany, transactionDate, reference, flagAdvice, addtionalData) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', [$company_code, $customer_number, $request_id, $channel_type, $customer_name, $currency_code, $paid_amount, $total_amount, $sub_company, $transaction_date, $reference, $detail_bills, $flag_advice, $addtional_data]);
        return response()
            ->json('The data was successfully inserted', 200)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

Comment: convert the JSON response to an array then take the values from it

Comment: how to use it with code ?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this,

```
//I am asuming that you are taking the json from you the $request
$responseData = json_decode($request->response);

//if you are using laravel 5.8 you need you Arr class like this Arr::only()
$data = array_only($responseData , ['CompanyCode', 'CustomerNumber', 'RequestID', 'ChannelType', 'CustomerName', 'PaidAmount', 'TotalAmount', 'SubCompany', 'TransactionDate', 'Reference', 'FlagAdvice', 'AddtionalData'])

DB::insert('insert into bca_company_payload (companyCode, customerNumber, requestID, channelType, customerName, paidAmount, totalAmount, subCompany, transactionDate, reference, flagAdvice, addtionalData) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', $data);
```

Comment: how to insert detailbills sir ?